# How to bundle a realm file with my app in swift4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I want to show persistent data when on the app first lunch on the device so the user can see it and I use realm as my database.

I was deceived after I filled my file with data on the simulator and now need to merge or to bundle the data file with my app.
Now I copied my default.realm file to dcouments then
I copied some related codes from stackoverflow in AppDelegate to bundle it but failed !

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    openRealm() //2
    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL) //3
    return true
}

//1
func openRealm() {
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")!
    let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    // Only need to copy the prepopulated `.realm` file if it doesn't exist yet
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: defaultPath){
        print("use pre-populated database")
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath, toPath: defaultPath)
            print("Copied")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

} //f
```

when I build the app always crashes and Xcode telling me that value is nill

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Comment: Where did you put the original `default.realm` file?

Comment: to documents in the project alongside plist.info and the other files. and I removed the one in simulator

Comment: Make sure the file's "Target Membership" is correct and that the "Build Phases" has it included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase

Comment: wowwww yess it wasn't checked on "Target Membership" like you said I hope you put this as answer so I can mark it, thank you I didn't' thought it'll be that easy!!

Comment: I don't know why would anyone put -1 on my question really frustrated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file's "Target Membership" is correct

[image: Target Maembership]

and that the file is included in the "Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources"

[image: Copy bundle resource]

And, yes, I've wasted hours on the is to